# pos_tag in NLTK does not tag sentences correctly

Tags: nltk

I have used this code:

```
# Step 1 : TOKENIZE
from nltk.tokenize import *
words = word_tokenize(text)

# Step 2 : POS DISAMBIG
from nltk.tag import *
tags = pos_tag(words)
```

to tag two sentences: 
John is very nice.  Is John very nice?

John in the first sentence was NN while in the second was VB! So, how can we correct pos_tag function without training back-off taggers?

Modified question:

I have seen the demonstration of NLTK taggers here http://text-processing.com/demo/tag/. When I tried the option "English Taggers & Chunckers: Treebank" or "Brown Tagger", I get the correct tags. So how to use Brown Tagger for example without training it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-ntlk-pos-tag-not-returnig-the-correct-pos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. Slightly longer answer: you can override specific words using a manually created UnigramTagger. See my answer for [custom tagging with nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919355/custom-tagging-with-nltk/5922373#5922373) for details on this method.

Comment: I trained all the taggers on text-processing.com using the train_tagger.py script from https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer. So you can either train the taggers yourself, or if you're interested in buying the taggers, contact me at http://text-processing.com/contact/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the bug using NLTK v3.0. I think now `nltk.pos_tag()` is fixed. As #Jacob mentioned, you can use Brown Corpus to train a tagger(nltk in python) as follows;

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
train_sents = brown.tagged_sents()
unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(train_sents)
tokens=nltk.word_tokenize("Is John very nice?")
tagged=unigram_tagger.tag(tokens)
tagged
```

But note that The tag set depends on the corpus that was used to train the tagger. The default tagger of nltk.pos_tag() uses the [Penn Treebank Tag Set](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html).