# TaggedCorpusReader and UnigramTagger in nltk (python)

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to use nltk to auto-categorize news articles in a very lo-fi way. I've created a custom corpus of word/tag pairs correlating to my categories (ie. teacher/EDU, computer/TECH, etc.) I've been reading around and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919355/custom-tagging-with-nltk) got me pretty close, but I'm still stuck.

Based on my code so far, how do I use my tagger to tag my sentence?

```
import nltk

# Loads my custom word/tag corpus
from nltk.corpus.reader import TaggedCorpusReader
reader = TaggedCorpusReader('taggers','.*')

#Sets up the UnigramTagger
default_tagger = nltk.data.load(nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER)
tagger = nltk.tag.UnigramTagger(model=reader.tagged_words(), backoff=default_tagger)

#Sample content
sent = 'The students went to school to ask their teacher what the homework for the day was but she told them to check their email.'
tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sent)

# Sad Panda
tagged = tagger.tag(tokens) 
# ^ produces AttributeError: 'ConcatenatedCorpusView' object has no attribute 'get'
```

It's also very possible that this is a poor way to go about doing what I'm trying to do, but it seems good enough for a first run. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taggers are for part-of-speech tagging, not text classification. Take a look at the reuters corpus - it categorizes news articles into multiple categories using a category file. Then look at the nltk.classify module and read up on how to train text classifiers.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, you pointed me in the right direction. The terminology was the key to finding the right path. Thanks!