# How to override the POS tags assigned to a text by nltk's pos_tag?

Tags: python, nltk

I am using pos_tag from nltk to tag text in a set of (untagged) technical documents and getting good results but it always tags words like "authenticated" as a verb when sometimes it can be used as an adjective. In other words, simply changing the tag would not work every time.

Is there a good way to override or correct the tagging results that take account of context?

Comment: Do you have a tagged corpus you could use to train your own PoS tagger?

Comment: No I do not. If I had a (manually) tagged corpus, I would use it to train the tagger.

Comment: Constraint Grammar can help you pick the correct one out of several tags depending on context.  I am not familiar enough with `nltk` to tell if this is directly useful. http://jaytaylor.com/blog/2010/04/03/learning-to-do-natural-language-processing-with-nltk/ appears to have something related.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919355/custom-tagging-with-nltk/5922373#5922373

Comment: Jacob, I saw that before I posted. Your answer makes it clear how to override tags on words treated as individual tokens but not how to deal with words whose tag varies with context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python NLTK pos\_tag not returning the correct part-of-speech tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-nltk-pos-tag-not-returning-the-correct-part-of-speech-tag)

Comment: This question predates the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your question boils down to "how can I improve my tagging?". The answer is, you need to build a better tagger. All non-trivial taggers take context into account, so it's not just a question of adding context sensitivity; it's already there, it's just failing in some cases.

The NLTK tagging model allows you to "chain" taggers, so that each one can take up where the other left off (e.g., the ngram tagger falls back on a regexp tagger for unknown words). It works like this:

```
t0 = nltk.DefaultTagger('N')
t1 = nltk.UnigramTagger(traindata, backoff=t0)
t2 = nltk.BigramTagger(traindata, backoff=t1)
```

`traindata` here is a *list* of already tagged sentences in the standard NLTK form: Each sentence is a list of tuples in the form `(word, tag)`. (You could use a different training corpus for each tagger, if you have reason to; you'll definitely want to use a consistent tagset). For example, here's a two-sentence long training corpus:

```
traindata = [ [ ('His', 'PRO'), ('petition', 'N'), ('charged', 'VD'), 
                ('mental', 'ADJ'), ('cruelty', 'N'), ('.', '.') ],
              [ ('Two', 'NUM'), ('tax', 'N'), ('revision', 'N'), ('bills', 'N'),
                ('were', 'V'), ('passed', 'VN'), ('.', '.') ] ]
```

Tagger `t2` (the one you'll use) will build a bigram model; if it sees unknown input, it will fall back on `t1`, which uses a unigram model; if that fails too, it will defer to `t0` (which just tags everything 'N').

You could add a special-purpose retagger to improve the default tagging, but of course you must first figure out what to have it do-- which is of course what you asked in the first place.

If the nltk tagger keeps making the same kinds of mistakes over and over, you can put together a corpus of corrections and train a re-tagger based on that. How much data you need will depend on how consistent the errors are. I've never tried this but the Brill tagger works by successively applying retagging rules, so perhaps it's the right tool to use.

The alternative would be to try building your own domain-specific tagged corpus: Tag a training set with the nltk tagger, correct it manually or semi-automatically, then train a tagger on it and try to get better performance on new data than with the default nltk tagger (perhaps by chaining the two taggers together).

Comment: Alexis, could you add some code that would allow me to accept this as an answer?

Comment: What kind of code did you want? I've added an example of how to chain taggers together. I'm afraid you didn't give enough details to allow me to adapt it to your problem.

Comment: I don't think that your original description is enough for someone else to be able to see what they should do.  The code sample is good.. can I edit the answer to show how to retrain in the unigram case?