# Custom POS tagging with NLTK (error)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to combine my own simple custom tagger with the nltk default tagger, in this case the perceptron tagger.

My code is as follows (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5922373/4772958)):

```
import nltk.tag, nltk.data

default_tagger = nltk.data.load(nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER)
model = {'example_one': 'VB' 'example_two': 'NN'}
tagger = nltk.tag.UnigramTagger(model=model, backoff=default_tagger)
```

However this gives the following error:

```
  File "nltk_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    default_tagger = nltk.data.load(nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER)
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_POS_TAGGER'
```

I tried to fix this by changing the default tagger to:

```
from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger
default_tagger = PerceptronTagger()
```

But then I get the following error:

```
  File "nltk_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    tagger = nltk.tag.UnigramTagger(model=model, backoff=default_tagger)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 340, in __init__
    backoff, cutoff, verbose)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 284, in __init__
    ContextTagger.__init__(self, model, backoff)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 125, in __init__
    SequentialBackoffTagger.__init__(self, backoff)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._taggers = [self] + backoff._taggers
AttributeError: 'PerceptronTagger' object has no attribute '_taggers'
```

Looking through the `nltk.tag` [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html) it seems that `_POS_TAGGER` no longer exists. However changing it to `_pos_tag` or `pos_tag` also didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer: use nltk 3.0.1 for now `pip install nltk==3.0.1`

Better answer: They changed the treebank tagger last September and it has a lot of other ramifications (we currently are fixed on 3.0.1 as the new tagger is worse at least for our needs).

This appears to work but I am unsure of how correct the code is:

```
class BackoffTagger:
    def __init__(self):
        self._taggers = [PerceptronTagger()]

model = {'example_one': 'VB', 'example_two': 'NN'}
tagger = nltk.tag.UnigramTagger(model=model, backoff=BackoffTagger())
tagger.tag(['example_one'])
>>> [('example_one', 'VB')]
```

Comment: Updated the answer with a code snippet that works with the latest nltk

Comment: Thanks so much! nltk 3.0.1 works fine but the 3.1 solution is preferable. It works great with your example. However when I introduce tokens that are not in the model, e.g. `'example_three'` I get an error in the `tag` function: 

`site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 61, in tag
    tags.append(self.tag_one(tokens, i, tags))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 81, in tag_one
    tag = tagger.choose_tag(tokens, index, history)
AttributeError: 'PerceptronTagger' object has no attribute 'choose_tag'`

Comment: In that case you may need to extend the PerceptronTagger class itself to add any needed functionality. This appears to be getting into whack-a-mole territory. I would consider asking the NLTK folks directly for guidance in the new world.

Comment: OK fair enough, I was wondering if there was a more simple fix. I'll stick to 3.0.1 then as that seems to work fine for now. Thanks again!

Comment: The Perceptron tagger (which is now the default NLTK tagger) does not inherit from the same class that the nGram taggers do, so using it as a backoff does not work.  This explains why you get the "object has no attribute 'choose_tag'" error.  But you can use the maxent_treebank_pos_tagger as the backoff

Answer (score 1):

Try following for custom tagging:

```
import nltk.tag, nltk.data
from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger
default_tagger = PerceptronTagger()
```

Define your model with custom tags:

```
model={"paining": "Reaction", "Itching":"Reaction", "Removed":"Reaction", "skin":"site"}

class BackoffTagger:
    def __init__(self):
        self._taggers = [PerceptronTagger()]

tagger = nltk.tag.UnigramTagger(model=model, backoff=BackoffTagger())
tagger.tag(['skin'])
```

**Output**:

> [('skin', 'site')]