# Custom tagger NLTK 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am working with nltk's default tagger to get a POS tag of the word but I am not getting the expected results:

```
>>> nltk.pos_tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("I want a watch"))
[('I', 'PRP'), ('want', 'VBP'), ('a', 'DT'), ('watch', 'NN')]
>>> nltk.pos_tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("Lets watch a movie"))
[('Lets', 'NNS'), ('watch', 'VBP'), ('a', 'DT'), ('movie', 'NN')]
```

As you can see above, the `pos_tag` function correctly tags the word `watch`. But in the below case:

```
>>> nltk.pos_tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("I want to read a book"))
[('I', 'PRP'), ('want', 'VBP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('read', 'VB'), ('a', 'DT'), ('book', 'NN')]

>>> nltk.pos_tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("I want to book a ticket"))
[('I', 'PRP'), ('want', 'VBP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('book', 'NN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('ticket', 'NN')]
```

It incorrectly predicts the tag for the word `book`. 
I know we can build a custom tagger but I would not prefer build a tagger from scratch just for one word. I am looking to improve the accuracy of the tagger for the word `book`. I referred to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919355/custom-tagging-with-nltk) but the latest version doesn't seem to have the method `nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER`.

Is there any possible workaround for this?

Comment: I have it correctly tagged as `'VB'` on my machine (NLTK3). Check this [Python NLTK pos_tag not returning the correct part-of-speech tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-nltk-pos-tag-not-returning-the-correct-part-of-speech-tag)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I agree with your comment that NLTK is not perfect. But I want to modify the existing algorithm's weight so that it correctly assigns tag for the word "book"

Comment: FWIW, the Stanford POS tagger (while slower) has provided me with much much better results. The default tagger isn't even able to process "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" correctly.

Comment: @Ares Thanks for your insight. I will give a try to Stanford tagger as well!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLTK `pos_tag` uses the [`PerceptronTagger`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/__init__.py#L110) by default. But you can use other *taggers* which have been trained on their respective datasets.

In the following case, the [treebank pos tagger](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/ccalas/tagsets/upenn.html) was used:

```
import nltk

tagger = nltk.data.load('taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle')
t = tagger.tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("I want to book a ticket"))
print(t)
# [('I', 'PRP'), ('want', 'VBP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('book', 'VB'), ('a', 'DT'), ('ticket', 'NN')]
#                                                         ^^ rightly tagged as verb
```

You can change tagger if you still don't get the desired results.

One can also evaluate the tagger on a corpus to get an idea of expected accuracies:

```
>>> corpus = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents()
>>> tagger.evaluate(corpus)
0.9956891414041082
```

Comment: Your answer seems fair enough. Is there any way to train an existing trained tagger? In your answer, can we further train the pre-trained treebank pos_tagger on another corpus?

Comment: @HiteshPaul If this answer solved your problem, you may consider accepting it. There should be workarounds to improve the accuracy of taggers but that isn't part of the original question

Comment: I tried using the sentence "Hey, will you book a show for me please?" but it give incorrect tags. Is there a way to train a pre-trained tagger??

Comment: @HiteshPaul  I haven't found a way to retrain taggers, but you can keep trying other taggers until you get good results, checkout the [Stanford POS tagger](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/stanford.html)